# Disassociating account from the rest of SE network

Tags: support, profile-page, user-accounts

Role playing related topics are sometimes such, that taken out of context, or read by someone who doesn't understand the context, would seem... quaint, and not necessarily in a positive way.

Rather than worry about stuff like this, I'd prefer my account here to not be publicly linked with the rest of SE. How should I proceed, and what are my options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to hide stacks so that they don't show up on your profile for other stacks or your general network profile.

[This link](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/hidecommunities/current) should take you to the options page for doing so; I *believe* hiding a specific community hides that community on your network profile and all other community profiles, regardless of which community profile you do it from, so you shouldn't need to do it from any/each other profile (double-check, though).

Answer (score 4):

Make another account, and use it instead, for either your gamer or professional persona.

The ship's already sailed on your existing content, but there's not all that much there.

While there are SE settings to "hide" stacks, using stack settings means you're trusting SE to maintain the separation for you, which is more convenient but leaves it in their hands. (As a commenter has mentioned, it looks like that hiding is not respected by the Android app, for example). If the separation is really, really important to you then you need to make different accounts so that the separation is in your hands not theirs. Use multiple browsers or private mode to be able to be signed in under two identities at once.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not worried about my posts so far.

Comment: Hmm, but this approach has the problem that I have to explicitly log out of the "main" SE account, and log in here, if I want to just check notifications?

Comment: Yes. No way around that. I run two accounts myself for that reason.  Use private mode, or two browsers, or whatever.

Comment: If you care to check my profile here now and see if you can get to my profiles in other pages, that would be great. I simply made all SE sites hidden, and changed profile details... Not ideal either, and obviously not bullet proof, but convenient.

Comment: Yes, I can get to your overall network profile easily from your local profile page.

Comment: Ah, I think it's because you're a mod. There's a tooltip balloon explaining that.

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir Yeah, you're right. I can't see any other accounts or your network account link when checking out your profile in Incognito mode (which you can verify by doing it yourself too). Looks effectively locked down to me.

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir When I visit your profile **through the Android app:** 1. It takes me directly to your network profile. 2. I can still see all your associated accounts, including RPG.SE, from there. So, either you've unhidden your associations, or the app does not currently observe that setting (and this might be a feature worth requesting).

Comment: Exactly.  Using whatever "stack settings" means you're trusting SE to maintain the separation for you, which is more convenient but leaves it in their hands.  If the separation is really, really important to you then you need to make different accounts so that the separation is in your hands not theirs.

Comment: @DanHenderson Thanks for that observation! I guess that's worth a bug report, if a feature labelled "hide" doesn't actually hide anything.